# Optimizing data scrape from NHL API using R

Tags: r, json

I am a novice with R and a total newbie with the NHL API. I wrote an R program to extract all of the goals recorded in the NHL's data repository accessed through the NHL API using the R "nhlapi" package. I have code that works, but it's ugly and slow, and I wanted to see if anyone has suggestions for improving it. I am using the nhl_games_feed function provided by nhlapi to pull all events, from which I select the goals. This function returns a JSON blob (list of lists of lists of lists ...) in R, which I want to convert into a proper data.table.

I pasted a stripped-down version of my code below. I understand that normal practice here would be to include a sample data blob with the code so that other users can recreate my problems, but the data blob is the problem.

When I ran the full version of my code last night, the "Loop through games" portion took about 11 hours, and the "Convert players list to columns" took about 2 hours. Unless I can find a way to push the column or row filtering into the NHL's system, I don't think I am likely to find a way to speed up the "Loop through games" portion. So my first question: Does anyone have any thoughts about how to extract a subset of columns or rows using the NHL API, or do I need to pull everything and process it on my end?

My other question related to the second chunk of code ("Convert players..."), which converts the resulting event data into a single row of scalar elements per event. The event data shows up in `lblob_feed[[1]]$liveData$plays$allPlays`, which contains one row of scalar elements per event, except that one of the elements is `..$allPlays$players`, which is itself a 4x5 dataframe. As a result, the only way that I could find to extract that data into scalar elements is the "Convert players..." loop. Is there a better way to convert this into a simple data.table?

Finally, any tips on other ways to end up with a comprehensive database of NHL events?

```
require("nhlapi")
require("data.table")
require("tidyverse")
require("hms")

assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())

# create small list of selected games, using NHL API game code format
cSelGames <- c(2021020001, 2021020002, 2021020003, 2021020004)

liNumGames <- length(cSelGames)
print(liNumGames)
# 34370 games in the full database

# =============================================================================
# Loop through games
# Pull data for one game per call
Sys.time()

dtGoals <- data.table()
for (liGameNum in 1:liNumGames) {
  # Pull the NHL feed blob for one selected game
  # 11 hours in the full version
  lblob_feed <- nhl_games_feed(gameId = cSelGames[liGameNum])

  # Select only the play (event) portion of the feed blob
  ldtFeed <- as.data.table(c(lblob_feed[[1]]$gamePk, lblob_feed[[1]]$liveData$plays$allPlays))
  setnames(ldtFeed, 1, "gamePk")
  # Check for games with no play data - 1995020006 has none and would kill execution
  if ('result.eventCode' %in% colnames(ldtFeed)) {
    # Check for missing elements in allPlays list
    #  team.triCode is missing for at least one game, probably for all-star games
    if (!('team.triCode' %in% colnames(ldtFeed))) {ldtFeed[, ':=' (team.triCode = NA)]}
    if (!('result.strength.code' %in% colnames(ldtFeed))) {ldtFeed[, ':=' (result.strength.code = NA)]}
    if (!('result.emptyNet' %in% colnames(ldtFeed))) {ldtFeed[, ':=' (result.emptyNet = NA)]}
    # Select the events and columns for the output data table
    ldtGoals_new <- ldtFeed[(result.eventTypeId == 'GOAL')
                    ,list(gamePk, result.eventCode, players, result.description
                          , team.triCode, about.period, about.periodTime
                          , about.goals.away, about.goals.home, result.strength.code, result.emptyNet)]

    # Append the incremental data table to the aggregate data table
    dtGoals <- rbindlist(list(dtGoals, ldtGoals_new), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
  }
}

# =============================================================================
# Convert players list to columns
# 2 hours in the full version
# 190686 goals in full table
# For each goal, the player dataframe is 4x5

Sys.time()

dtGoal_player <- data.table()
for (i in 1:dtGoals[,.N]) {
  # convert rows with embedded dataframes into multiple rows with scalar elements
  s_result.eventCode <- dtGoals[i,result.eventCode]
  dtGoal_player_new <- as.data.table(dtGoals[i,players[[1]]])
  dtGoal_player_new[, ':=' (result.eventCode=s_result.eventCode)]
  dtGoal_player <- rbindlist(list(dtGoal_player, dtGoal_player_new), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
}

# drop players element
dtGoals[, players:=NULL]

# clean up problem with duplicated rows with playerType=Assist
dtGoal_player[, lag.playerType:=c('nomatch', playerType[-.N]), by=result.eventCode]
dtGoal_player[, playerType2:=ifelse((playerType==lag.playerType),'Assist2',playerType)]

# transpose multiple rows per event into single row with multiple columns for playerType
dtGoal_player_t <- dcast.data.table(dtGoal_player, result.eventCode ~ playerType2
                                    , value.var='player.id', fun.aggregate=max)

# =============================================================================
# Merge players data into dtGoals
Sys.time()

dtGoals <- merge(dtGoals, dtGoal_player_t, by="result.eventCode")

Sys.time()
```

Comment: First step is to remove the bind function from loops.  Store all of your values in a vector or list and then bind after the loop.  I suggest googling the “R Inferno”

Comment: See chapter 2 https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf